# Automatically set Projects' milestones to Project Center timeline

Tags: 2013, project-server, timeline

In Project server, on projects page/project center timeline with all projects is displayed, bellow it there is gantt list view of all projects.

I got a task to display all milestones of every project on Project center timeline page. Is this possible automatically or manually at all?
If yes, how can it be done?